# Javascript: pick only certain properties in Object

Tags: javascript

I have configuration object for my features:

```
const features = {
    "feature1": {
        "value": 1,
        "description": ""
    },
    "feature2": {
        "value": 2,
        "description": ""
    }
}
```

How to transform it to feature/value format like

```
{"feature1": 1, "feature2": 2}
```

My variant is below, but I feel it's not elegant

```
let config = {};

config = Object.keys(features).map(
    k  => config[k] = flags[k]["value"]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ES6` spread syntax with `Object.assign()` and `map()`.

```js
const features = {"feature1":{"value":1,"description":""},"feature2":{"value":2,"description":""}}

var result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(features).map(k => ({[k]: features[k].value})))
console.log(result)
```

Or you can use `Object.keys()` and `reduce()`

```js
const features = {"feature1":{"value":1,"description":""},"feature2":{"value":2,"description":""}}

var result = Object.keys(features).reduce((r, e) => (r[e] = features[e].value, r), {})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Another handy way SelectQL.js is inspired by Structured Query Language (SQL) for accessing and manipulating Objects in an easy and familiar way. It supports complex Objects and Arrays using Builder Design Pattern.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/selectql.js